# CustomViewController's view's layout becomes wrong when added as subview

Tags: xcode, swift, layout, interface, subview

I have created a CustomViewController and layed it out in interface builder. Then I am all set to use the CustomViewController's view as a subview in another viewcontroller but when I add it to the other viewcontroller the layout of the custom uivewcontroller becomes wrong.

What can cause this? What is the propper way to do this?

The whole project can be found here https://github.com/agustr/STHLMPubCrawl just download and run (in an iphone 5 simulator). If there is any question about how it should look you can just move the initial view pointer to the 'place view controller cene'

this is the code:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GPPlaceViewController") as? GPPlaceViewController
    if vc != nil{

        vc?.view.layer.borderWidth = 4
        vc?.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor

        self.GPPlaceView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
        self.GPPlaceView.layer.borderWidth = 2

        vc?.view.frame.size =  self.GPPlaceView.frame.size

        self.GPPlaceView.addSubview(vc!.view)
    }
    else {
        print("could not load GPPlacePageViewController from storyboard")
    }
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Before you add the view as a subview are you setting it's frame?

Comment: Good point but alas not the one I am struggling with... I have struggled with it before though.

Comment: Only other things i can think of is calling layoutIfNeccisary() or didMoveToParentViewController()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure if this method of adding a VC's view to another view is wrong or outdated but I seem to remember it working at some point. I contacted apple and they told me to use a ContainerView. It is supposedly explained in detail in this talk 'Implementing UIViewController Containment' https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/.

The biggest problem I had when using the containment View was that you can not drag the segue in interface builder but you have to right click or controll click to point the segue to the appropriate place. Then you can treat that segue as any other in your parent viewcontroller that is to say the viewcontroller that contains the container view.